# How to use Google Play Install Referrer API in Ionic?

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic4, install-referrer

I have been struggling over the past week figuring out how to use [Google Play Install Referrer API](https://developer.android.com/google/play/installreferrer/igetinstallreferrerservice), in an Ionic app. I have tried using the following approaches:

*Approach 1*: **InstallBroadcast**

I installed a cordova plugin called `cordova-plugin-installreferrer` and a npm module `install-referrer`. When I try to build the app in development mode, I get the response as empty array. But when I build it in production mode, I get `plugin_not_found` error. (PS: I have added it to the providers in the app.module.ts)

```
import { InstallReferrer } from 'install-referrer/ngx';
...
constructor(
  private installReferrer: InstallReferrer
) {
  this.installReferrer.getReferrer().then(data => {
      alert(JSON.stringify(data));
  }).catch((err) => {
      alert(JSON.stringify(err));
  });
}
```

I also realized the **InstallBroadcast is deprecated now**. We have to switch to Play Install Referrer API.

*Approach 2*: **Play Install Referrer API**

I tried installing a cordova plugin called `cordova-install-referrer-api`. And tried the following code:

```
declare var referrer: any;
...
initializeApp() {
  try{
    referrer.get().then((referrer) => {
      alert(JSON.stringify(referrer));
    });
  }catch(err){
    alert(err);
  }
...
```

Getting the following error: `ReferenceError: referrer is not defined`

Please help me get the referrer correctly, also let me know if I'm doing something wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your Approach 2: You've declared a variable `referrer` but I can't see the initialization in your code and the error you're getting is also not defined. So, I think you've not defined it.

Remove the declared variable and replace your code with this:

```
cordova.plugins.referrer.get().then((referrer) => {
    console.log(referrer);
    // Remove these comments, just an example from the original API
    // Result:
    // {
    //     clickTimestamp: 0,
    //     installBeginTimestamp: 0,
    //     referrer: "utm_source=google-play&utm_medium=organic"
    // } 

}).catch((error) => {
});
```

And check if it works. The code is referenced from the [Official Repo](https://github.com/byorty/cordova-install-referrer-api#usage).

Comment: I thought we had a different approach to use cordova plugins in ionic, turns out this is only the current way to use cordova plugins. *Note*: Don't forget to add `declare let cordova: any;` and the above code from official doc works absolutely fine.

Comment: @CraziestHacker Glad, it helped.